# Finding occurrences of a string in a Word document - problem if string is found in a table

Tags: vba

Would appreciate some help with this problem.
I need to find all occurrences of a string in a Word document. When the string is found some complicated editing is performed on it. Sometimes no editing is needed and the string is left untouched. When all that is taken care of, I continue looking for the next occurrence of the string. Until the end of the document.

I wrote a routine to do that :

- It starts by defining a Range (myRange) that covers the whole document.
- Then a Find.Execute is performed.
- When an occurrence is found I do the editing work.
- Meanwhile myRange has been automatically redefined to cover only the found region (this is well documented in the VBA WORD documentation > FIND Object).
- Then I redefine myRange to cover the portion of the text from the end of the previous found region down to the end of the text.
- I iterate this until the end of the document.

This routine works well EXCEPT when an occurrence of the string is found in a TABLE. Then it is impossible to redefine myRange to cover the region from the end of the previous found down to the end of the text. In the redefinition VBA insists on including the previous found region (actually the whole TABLE). So when I iterate it keeps finding the same occurrence again and again and looping for ever.

What follows is a simplified version of my routine. It does nothing it is just to illustrate the problem. If you run it on a document where the string "abc" appears you will see it running happily to completion. But if your document has an occurrence of "abc" in a TABLE the routine loops for ever.

```
Sub moreTests()

Dim myRange As Range
Dim lastCharPos As Integer

Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range
lastCharPos = myRange.End

myRange.Find.ClearFormatting

With myRange.Find
    .Text = "abc"
End With

While myRange.Find.Execute = True
    'An occurrence of "abc" has been found
    MsgBox (myRange.Text)
    MsgBox ("Range starts at : " & myRange.Start & "; Range ends at : " & myRange.End)
    'myRange has been redefined to encompass only the found region (the "abc" string)
    'Perform whatever editing work is needed on the string myRange.Text ("abc")
    'Now redefine myRange to cover the remainder of the document
    myRange.Start = myRange.End
    myRange.End = lastCharPos
    MsgBox ("Range starts at : " & myRange.Start & "; Range ends at : " & myRange.End)
Wend


End Sub 'moreTests
```

I have several ways in mind to circumvent this problem. But none of them is simple, let alone 'elegant'. Does someone know if there is a 'standard' / 'proven' way of avoiding this problem ?

Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: Using 'Set MyRange = Document.Range([Start], [End])' you can easily reset the range after each use where Start = [current MyRange.End] and End = [Document.Range.End]

Comment: You may find the .Duplicate method of the Word.Range object useful in this context.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have not been able to make either work. Problem is that Find.Execute does not accept a Range that starts halfway through a row of a table. It always automatically extends the Range to include the full row. So my routine finds an occurrence of string "abc" somewhere in a cell of a table and, however I shrink the Range for the next Find, Find.Execute always includes the full row where the string has been found. The same occurrence keeps getting found all the time, the routine loops for ever.